# _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')

Tags: flutter

I have json as below

```
{
    "title": "DVG's Critique of the Congress High",
    "body": [],
    "field_body": {
        "und": [
            {
                "value": "<p>The swift emergence of the High Command culture, which spawned the aforementioned dwarfs at many key-points revealed perhaps its most ugly face in the form of perpetually warring factions both in the Government and Party. 
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

Json has the two body fields. If body is null or 0 I should load the data from field_body but when I declare that in getData its giving me error- type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'. Could anyone please help me with this.

```
    var data = await http.get(url);
    var jsonData = json.decode(utf8.decode(data.bodyBytes));
    return DetailData(
        jsonData['title'],
        jsonData['body']['und'][0]['value'] == 0
            ? jsonData['field_body']['und'][0]['value']
            : jsonData['body']['und'][0]['value'],
        jsonData['field_image_wp']['und'][0]['filename'],
        jsonData['name']);
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess your second positional argument of DetailData class is typed as int, and you're trying to give it a String value

Answer (score 0):

Json key **"body"** does not have any **"und"** property. It just a empty list. Either you have mistakenly written `field_body` as `body` in line 385 or you have forgortten to add `und` property to `body` in Json.